# Function.name empty in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, function, microsoft-edge

I have some code that works fine in Chrome:

```
var someFunc = function(thisIsAFunction) {
   var functionName = thisIsAFunction.name;
}
```

The docs say that this code will work in all browsers except IE 11, for which I have a polyfill method. Recently, Edge is reporting that 'thisIsAFunction.name' is empty. My polyfill doesn't kick in because thisIsAFunction.name is not undefined. The value, of course, should be the functions name.

Any idea of what's going on? Is this just a bug in Edge that hasn't been reported yet? I can code around it by checking for an empty value in name, but I hate doing that (but I will if that's the only option)

Comment: I actually dont think that using `Function.prototype.name` is a good idea.

Comment: I think it's a fine idea, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: Anonymous functions have an empty name. Are you by any chance calling `someFunc` like this: `someFunc(function() { ... });`?

Comment: hmmm.. I was about to say no, but it just occurs to me that

var func = function() {}

is an anonymous function just set to a variable. I'll see if that's my issue.

Comment: `var func = function() {}` is not an anonymous function ASFAIK. Just checked in Chrome and its name is `"func"` as expected. Not sure how Edge is treating them though.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here is that with Edge, you have to name your functions like this:

```
var someFunc = function SomeFunc() {}
```

if you want SomeFunc.name to equal 'SomeFunc'. Not ideal, but there it is all the same. What a world.